# Is Alias and CTE are same?

Tags: sql

Is

> select id from (select * from employee
>   ) as t

is same as

> ;with temp as (select * from employee)
>   select id from temp

?????

Both will return same result.But regarding performance oriented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *in your example* they are the same, you should view the execution plan to see any differences in how they work and hence performance. If you 'include execution plan' in SSMS and execute both queries in one batch, you will get a 'Query cost (relevant to the batch)' which will tell you which query performs better. I would guess that they are equivalent.

The advantage of a CTE (your second statement) over a derived table is that they can reference themselves and be used for recursion.

Comment: I examined the Client Statistics for the both type of queries, i found the total execution times are same. How do i know the space occupied in Memory for the execution.
Thanks for your response

Comment: Look at the execution plan, hover over the arrows and the tool tip should give you more information.

Comment: A CTE can be used for more than just recursion. They're really more like a temporary named view or a query macro.

Comment: Yes, that was the question, they work in the same way as derived tables. But they have the main advantage of being able to reference themselves for recursion which a derived table cannot do, they can also be referenced multiple times which avoids duplication of sql. I prefer CTE's as they are more readable.